# Is Firebase with App Attest and DeviceCheck able to detect that the App is running on a Jailbroken Iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, firebase-app-check, devicecheck

I see jailbreak detection questions being asked, but they mostly prior to DeviceCheck. I understand that AppCheck with Play's Integrity API is able to check if the App is running on "[... a genuine Android device](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity)". Is AppCheck with App Attest and DeviceCheck able to detect that the App is running on a jailbroken device? Is that even part of the purpose of the service?

If not, what is the advised way of detecting jailbreaking?

Comment: Jailbreak detection is almost always an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Why is running on a jailbroken device problematic? What are you actually trying to protect against?

Comment: If you can't trust that the user's device is secure, then allowing/relying  on security features, like touch id (https://codeshare.frida.re/@ivan-sincek/ios-touch-id-bypass/) would have fewer use cases. So, I do see value on the possibility of having a way to detect if the user's device is jailbroken, even if not 100% effective.

Comment: Jailbreak can be detected with freerasp checker also.